# Context(right-click) menu Long loading times when Network connected

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, context-menu

The right-click context menu takes 10+ seconds to open on any file/folder. The delay does not change between repetitively right-clicking on the same file/folder. I also sometimes get explorer crashes.

There is only a delay when I am connected to a network (wired or wifi). It also doesn't matter if it is a internet connection.

---

I have disabled all context menu/shell entries using CCleaner. Including the [Norton's `NavShExt.dll` which is known to cause delays](http://shellfix.nirsoft.net/shell_problems_list.html).

To make sure my HDD wasn't bad or failing:

- Ran `sfc /scannow` with no errors found.
- Ran the `C:->Properties->Tools->Error Checking` utility and it fixed some errors with no issue but decided to stop and do it from boot. I ran `chkdsk C: /v /r /f` at boot and it was able to fix everything("4 KB in bad sectors"): "No further action is required."
- Defragmented the C: drive where my OS and other data is located. I also have a D: partition and external networked NAS for data.

---

I made several dumps from WinDbg to try to see why explorer was crashing by attaching to the `explorer.exe` and doing stuff until it crashed. `.dump /m mydump.dmp`

When capturing dumps with WinDbg, I get a constant stream of CLR exceptions(not sure if normal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have any context menu items/programs that are in [this list](http://shellfix.nirsoft.net/shell_problems_list.html).

Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to view all context menu entries that are enabled/active. The program is a bit old looking and hard to wrangle at first, but gives a complete picture of everything enabled. Disable all non-microsoft entries one by one until the problem goes away.

Once you have disabled/enabled any entries, you need to restart `explorer.exe` before the changes will be active. You can restart `explorer.exe` by opening the Task Manager(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>), selecting `Windows Explorer` from the `Processes->App` list and pressing `Restart`.

*Note:* CCleaner also has a context menu utility(`Tools->Startup->Context Menu`) but it doesn't list all entries that could affecting the load times.

---

In order to manually debug `explorer.exe`, you can use WinDbg:

1. `File->Attach to Process` or `F6`
2. Sort `By Executable`
3. Scroll down and select `explorer.exe`. *Make sure to select `explorer.exe` and not the session instance in the collapsible menu.*
4. Press "OK" and wait for it to give you a console/text-input at the bottom of the command screen.
5. Type "g" and enter. Your explorer will freeze until you give it this command.
6. Look for any  `ModLoad` entries that appear after the delay and the context menu appears. Any one of these could be the culprit.

If the explorer is crashing and you want to capture a dump file, start with steps #1-5 above then:

1. Do whatever action(s) that freezes `explorer.exe`. You will probably notice it doesn't crash like normal because WinDbg has stepped in and is waiting for the next command.
2. Make a dump file by running: `.dump /m mydump.dmp`
3. The dump file will be located wherever WinDbg was installed. You can also use a full file path to the desktop but it not always easy to have the path handy in the clip board to paste in.

---

The solution in my case was to disable the Perforce `P4EXP.P4EXPContextMenuExtension` entry using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

> P4EXP.P4EXPContextMenuExtension
>   Location: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\P4EXP\2014.2.95.9073__null\P4EXP.dll
>   From: P4Merge
>   Company: Perforce

This delay was mentioned in the [Perforce r14.2 notes](http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/doc/user/p4expnotes.txt) but it probably regressed because I have version 2014.2 and still had the problem:

> #975324 (Bug #75847)
>   P4EXP no longer builds the Perforce context menu on right
>       click of an object in Windows Explorer. This could previously
>       cause a substantial delay in display of the Windows Explorer
>       context menu if Perforce environment variables were unset or
>       incorrectly set or if the targeted server is offline.

Comment: Excellent answer and tip for troubleshooting my related "right-click image and 30-second delay" issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have already faced this problem and solved it.

I solved this problem using **CCleaner** as like below:

1. Open **CCleaner.**
2. Click on left tab to **Tools**.
3. Click on top tab to **Context Menu**.
4. Click on **BthSendToContextMenuExt** (File:C:\WINDOWS\System32\BSAppShEXT.dll)
5. Click on **Disable** button on right side.

If you fail to solve this problem by this way, you may follow this link
http://windowsreport.com/file-explorer-slow-windows-10/

Comment: The accepted answer  refers to `CCleaner` already.